# Moduli spaces of rank 2 stable bundles over curves as projective varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gauge-theory

Let $\Sigma$ be a Riemann surface of genus $g$. Let's consider the moduli space of rank $2$ stable vector bundles with determinant $L$ such that $\deg(L)$ is odd. Denote this space by $\mathcal{M}_{\Sigma}(2,L)$. It is well-known that $\mathcal{M}_{\Sigma}(2,L)$ is isomorphic to the intersection of quadrics in $\mathbb{P}^5$ when $g=2$ by [Newstead](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=237500) and [Narasimhan-Ramanan](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?pg1=INDI&s1=203598%20and%20196915&sort=Newest&vfpref=html&r=7&mx-pid=242185).

Question: do we have a similar "classical description" of $\mathcal{M}_{\Sigma}(2,L)$ as a projective variety when $g \geq 3$?

Comment: If the curve is hyperelliptic, there is an analogous description.

Comment: That sounds interesting, what's the reference for hyperelliptic curves?

Comment: U. V. Desale and S. Ramanan, ‘Classification of vector bundles of rank 2 on hyperelliptic curves’, Invent. Math. 38 (1976) 161–185.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful!